# how can i disable options from drop down list if they are in my database

Tags: php, html, database

i have this drop down list

```
<form action="order.php" method="GET" >
<p>Select Toy:</p>
 <select id="selecttoy"  name="selecttoy">
  <option value="73438">73438 Cadillac Presidential Limousine Ronald Reagan 1983 NIB</option>
  <option value="56456">56456 Giocher Z01 Z15 115 ARMOURED </option>
  <option value="55641">55641 Limo of president John Kennedy</option>
  <option value="61236">61236 Limousine (Chermenko)</option>
  <option value="54551">54551 ZIL 114 Limousine (Brezhnev)</option>
  <option value="15212">15212 OLYMPIC AIRWAYS BOEING 737-300 SX-BLA </option>

  <option value="54545">54545 OLYMPIC AIRWAYS AIRBUS A320 SX-QAQ </option>
  <option value="65466">65466 DIE CAST OLYMPIC AIRWAYS DOUGLAS DC-3 SX-BAH</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and a database which contains a table named "orderstable". in this table i have the field "ToyCode". each option i choose the value goes in that field. but i want to disable that value from the list to as soon as it is in the database (in other words i do not want people to be able to order the same thing twice)...thing is i can not find how....so i need some help please

thanks in advance

edit that is the sql code (with some test entries i put in)

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.2.11
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Φιλοξενητής: 127.0.0.1
-- Χρόνος δημιουργίας: 07 Ιουν 2015 στις 00:20:28
-- Έκδοση διακομιστή: 5.6.21
-- Έκδοση PHP: 5.6.3

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Βάση δεδομένων: `3890ask3_db`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Δομή πίνακα για τον πίνακα `orderstable`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orderstable` (
  `ClName` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `ClSurname` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `ClEmail` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  `ToyCode` int(11) NOT NULL,
`OrderID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Usern` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Cdate` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Άδειασμα δεδομένων του πίνακα `orderstable`
--

INSERT INTO `orderstable` (`ClName`, `ClSurname`, `ClEmail`, `ToyCode`, `OrderID`, `Usern`, `Cdate`) VALUES
('mar', 'kyr', 'dgggfd@vvv.ff', 61236, 9, 'marinak_13', '2015-06-06'),
('mar', 'kyr', 'dgggfd@vvv.ff', 73438, 10, 'marinak_13', '2015-06-06');

--
-- Ευρετήρια για άχρηστους πίνακες
--

--
-- Ευρετήρια για πίνακα `orderstable`
--
ALTER TABLE `orderstable`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`OrderID`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT για άχρηστους πίνακες
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT για πίνακα `orderstable`
--
ALTER TABLE `orderstable`
MODIFY `OrderID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=11;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: Please show your current PHP code and database structure too. Also, don't you want people to be able to order the same product twice?

Comment: select from `orderstable` and save to an array. put your dropdown values in an array. Then use [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to find the values in your dropdown array that are not in your table array, and only show those values.

Comment: @GolezTrol yes.i don't want people to be able to order the same product twice.i 'll put the sql code of my database now :)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand what you trying to do. Is this html generated by php? Can't you just check before each option if value exists in database table?

I would do something like this before each option:

```
if (in_array($value, $arr)) {$disabled="disabled";} else {$disabled="";}
echo '<option value="'.$value.'" '.$disabled.'></option>';
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to store the options in the database (rather than the HTML code). Then have a boolean (or yes/no) field called purchased (or chosen/taken, etc.). Then you just have to use an SQL statement similar to this:

```
select id, toydescription from toytable where purchased = "no";
```

Or just have a table for unsold toys and then move them to the sold toys table after they have been sold:

```
select id, toydescription from unsold_toys_table;
```

Once you have those values have a loop that will loop through each row returned and create a select statement from them.

It is much easier this way as you don't have to keep editing HTML code when you have new items to sell, you just add the new items to the database and your html code will automatically update for you.